# Automatically wake up notebooks not on the ethernet

Tags: linux, backup, unix, script, wake-on-lan

I am looking for an automated backup system and I like bacula. I have 3 Notebooks and a Desktop computer that need regular backup. Now I don't want to let them run all night just to do the backuping, so I was thinking I could use wake-on-lan to have bacula wake up the machines, then do the backups, and shut them down afterswards. While this may work with devices on the ethernet, it won't work with the Notebooks on the wifi. So is it possible to have the Notebooks schedules to automatically wake up from suspend or shutdown ?

Or is it possible to interject a shutdown command if it is after a certain hour and call the bacula director to start the backup now?

I'm new to controlling the linux system using scripts, so any hints on how and where to start are greatly appreciated.

Thanks alot for your help, input and ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is my backup solution, it consists of two scripts:

1.) I replaced the standard
    /usr/lib/hal/scripts/hal-system-power-suspend
script with the following code to ensure that every time the computer goes to sleep (e.g. close the lid) it will wake up for the backup:

```
#!/bin/sh

#Determine when to wake up computer
waketime="01:30"
waketimesec="0"

if [ `date --date=$waketime +%s` -gt `date +%s` ]
then
  echo today
  waketimesec=`date --date=$waketime +%s`
else
  echo tomorrow
  waketimesec=`date --date="tomorrow $waketime" +%s`
fi


#Determine switch sleep modus to choose
state=`cat /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/AC0/state | grep on-line`
if [ "$state" = '' ]
then
  echo Computer on battery mode
  sudo /usr/sbin/pm-suspend           
else
  echo Computer on AC mode
  sudo rtcwake -m mem -t $waketimesec

  state=`cat /proc/acpi/ac_adapter/AC0/state | grep on-line`
  if [ "$state" = '' ]
  then
  sudo /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
  fi
fi
```

Notice that no backups are made if the AC-Adapter is unplug and the computer is running on battery.

2.) The second script does the actual backup and is triggered by cron a few minutes after the wake-up. It wakes up the remote destination computer, mounts a smbfs share, performs a differential backup using backintime and shuts down the remote computer, then puts the local pc back to sleep:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Wake up destination computer and sleep...
wakeonlan <mac_address>
date
echo ..sleep for 90s #the time your computer needs to boot and start smb
sleep 90
echo Mounting share..
sudo smbmount //<ip_address>/backup_folder /home/<user>/local_folder/ -o username=<user>,password=<pass>,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=1000,user
echo ..share mounted!
echo Starting backup!
backintime --backup > backintime.log
echo Backup finished, giving it time to settle..
sleep 10
echo Unmounting share..
sudo smbumount /home/<user>/local_folder/
sleep 5
echo Shutdown remote computer...
ssh '<user>@<ip_address>' "sudo shutdown -h now"
echo Going back to sleep..
/usr/lib/hal/scripts/hal-system-power-suspend
```

For every sudo command use visudo to grant superuser rights. Use publickey authorization to avoid password-prompts on the ssh command.

Now you have fresh backups every night with minimal power-consumption. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

My answer didn't get moved over from SO.  Hunh.

The command you might want to search for is **apmsleep**, although it might be Debian-specific.

Comment: `apmsleep` is also present in recent versions of RHEL.

Comment: thanks for the hint, looking for apmsleep I found rtcwake:

rtcwake -m mem -t `date --date="tomorrow 01:30" +%s`

will put the notebook to sleep and bring it back at 1:30 in the following morning


the only problem is, that it needs to be run as su, is there a tricky to avoid that?

Now I could send a magic packet to the fileserver to wake it up and perform the backup, but how can I remotely shut down the fileserver afterwards?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

*So is it possible to have the Notebooks schedules to automatically wake up from suspend or shutdown?*

Yes it's possible. I have done this a long time ago - however i can't remember exactly how but it was not hard, from what i remember there was a configuration file you simply edited.

Try looking at the kernel configuration, should be APM/ACPI related. Good luck.

EDIT: Found the command, it's `apmsleep`. I think that's what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is well known for the users of linux-based home PVR systems like MythTV (they want their video recording machine wake up when there is something to record on) and MythTV wiki gives a lot of information on this topic: http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/System_wakeup

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this, would probably be to set the wakeup-timer in the BIOS. So the computer always boots up at backup-time. And then write a script to make sure no-one is logged in, and the backup is completed for a shutdown.